# What is the difference between maven parameter with double quotes ("") and without it

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I was having problems with a maven plugin in my work. after debugging the issue I found that one of the parameters was not being parsed correctly.

```
<additionalparam>
    -d "${project.build.directory}/apidocs"
</additionalparam>
```

So I tried removing the double quotes symbols, and then all work as expected.

```
<additionalparam>
    -d ${project.build.directory}/apidocs
</additionalparam>
```

The parameter with double quotes was parsing to this string.

`"C:UsersJohnDocumentsconnector\target/apidocs"`

and the other one

`"C:\Users\John\Documents\slack-connector\target/apidocs"`

Does maven evaluate the parameter when quoted?

Thanks.

Comment: Because java strings use the backslash as an escape. Looks like it's being evaluated when quoted.

Comment: do not put additional information in the comments, **edit** the question and put them there, if they are in the comments they might as well not be there to begin with

Comment: Thanks Dave, Maven evaluate parameters when quoted.